# How to use SuperScrolloRama with Backbone.js Views

Tags: events, backbone.js, view, superscrollorama

I am trying to understand how to use a plugin like http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/, with Backbone.js by integrating it into my Views. I know that I need to hook into the backbone View-Events, but I want to do a horizontal scroll with the plugin, and I don't know of a horizontal scroll-event. How can I still utilize the plugin? Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Views:

```
var ArtistsView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
    tagName: 'ul',
    initialize: function () {     
        this.cleanUp();   
        $("body").attr('id','artists');
        this.render();
    },


     events: {
      "click div.open" : "largeArtViewOpen",
        "click div.close" : "largeArtViewClose",
     },

    render: function () {
        this.collection.each(function(model) {
            var artistView = new ArtistView({ model: model });
            this.$el.append(artistView.render().el);

        }, this);
        console.log('and a new view was rendered!')
        return this;


    },

    cleanUp: function(){
        if (this != null) {
           this.remove();
           this.unbind();
           console.log('View was removed!');
        } 
    },

    largeArtViewOpen: function(e){
        var thisArt = $(e.currentTarget).parent().attr("class");
            console.log(thisArt);
            $("#open-view, li."+thisArt).show();
        },

    largeArtViewClose: function(e){
        //var thisArt = $(e.currentTarget).parent().attr("class");

        console.log('clicked!');
        $("#open-view, ul#large li").hide();

        },

    scrollFx: function(){

            var controller = $.superscrollorama({
                isVertical:false
            });

            controller.addTween('h2#fade-it', TweenMax.from( $('h2#fade-it'), .5, {css:{opacity: 0}}), 800);
            //$('h2#fade-it').css({'color':'#dbdbdb'});
            console.log('scroll message!');

    },

}); 

var ArtistView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName:'li',
    className:'artistLink not-active',

    render: function(){
        this.id = this.model.get('idWord')+"-menu-item";
        this.$el.attr('id', this.id).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;

    },

});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, in the past 3 days since I've asked this question, I've spent some time trying different scrollable 'targets' for Superscrollorama...Document vs. Window vs. Body vs. other DOM elements within the HTML, and the questions that I've had to consider are, should the scroll event be bound to the View's top element? Should it be bound to the body, but initialized in the view? In both cases I tried, I couldn't get the scroll events to continuously fire...this may just be due to bad code, but I couldn't make it happen.

So, what I arrived at, was, avoiding the view entirely: I instantiating and called Superscrollorama in a function called scrollFx() within a separate 'helper.js' document, and then called scrollFx() from my view's router.

I'm thinking I will just empty the target's styles and unbind any existing scroll events in the beginning of scrollFx(), before I call the Superscrollorama function so that the resulting scroll styles/animations are cleaned up, and events aren't exponentially bound.

I'm still very much working through these issues, though now the scroll events are working, so if anyone happens to read through this train of thought, please feel free to add your two sense, especially, if you have better ideas about re-implementing the Superscrollorama function within the View itself.

Thanks.